# Flash / AS3 - How to Disable Child SWF Mouse Clicks Without Disabling Mouse Hover Events

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash browser application that loads in a child swf using a Loader object.

The child swf has a mouseclick listener that calls nativateToUrl, and opens a new web page. It also contains mouse hover events that make things in the swf move around.

This application that does the loading is like a container for the child swf and should open a *different* web page when it is clicked. So essentially I want to suppress the child swf mouseEvent and listen for the mouse click on the container swf, opening the new URL.

I have heard of other people putting an invisible sprite over the original content so that the child swf doesn't actually catch a mouseclick event. However, this won't work in my case because then it doesn't get the mouse hover events either. I want the mousehover events to go through and make the things in the child swf move but also suppress the click event.

So, for all the flash masterminds out there... is this possible? And how can I do it?

:) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress all `MouseEvent.CLICK` events from reaching a loaded SWF, you can do the following:

Let's assume you have the following setup:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("child.swf"));
addChild(loader);
```

What you can do, is listen on the capture phase for a click event on the Loader:

```
loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler, true);//the third parameter (true) tells flash to listen on the capture phase of an event's lifecycle
```

Then in the click handler from that, cancel the event so it doesn't propagate down to the loaded SWF:

```
function handler(e:Event):void {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

If you don't understand the phases of events, this diagram from Adobe may help:

[image]

[Source](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html)

As an aside, if you wanted to suppress all mouse stuffs from the SWF, a much better way (instead of adding an invisible sprite) is to just do this:

```
loader.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: No problem!  It's a good question.  Please accept the answer (gray checkmark under the voting buttons) if you feel this properly answers your question.

Comment: UPDATE - sorry Batman, this doesn't work. The Mouse Event never gets fired. It seems to work in the IDE flash player but not in browsers... :/

Comment: Tested some more.  I can tell you this 100% works.  I can send you test source files if you'd like.  Your issue must be in the implementation.  Update your question to include the actual code you're using.

Comment: http://batmantest.azurewebsites.net/test.html   (main test)  http://batmantest.azurewebsites.net/childSwf.html (the child swf alone)  http://batmantest.azurewebsites.net/test.zip   (all the source files)

Comment: ok. I did get it working, but I had to do _swfLoader.content or chld of _swfLoader and also get past security sandbox problems. Works now though. thanks.

Comment: It would have been good to mention in your question that the swf's are being loaded from another domain.   Please accept the answer if you feel it properly answers the question.