# AS3 Dragging issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

i have a list of movie clips which each has many child's

```
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, fl_TouchBeginHandler);
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, fl_TouchMoveHandler);

var last_posY: Number;
function fl_TouchBeginHandler(eve: TouchEvent): void {

    last_posY= eve.stageY;
}
function fl_TouchMoveHandler(eve: TouchEvent): void {
    for(var i=0;i<movieClipsArray.lenght;i++){
        movieClipsArray[i].y-=eve.stageY - delta_posY;
 }
    last_posY= eve.stageY;
}
```

im trying scroll the list of movie clips every thing works when I drage in a part of the stage where is empty but while i drage on movie clips it has a problem (for example while scrolling it shakes without any reason)and after some debuging i found out when i drage and the eve.target changs(from one of the movie clips nested childs to an other)the eve.stageY changes a wired way that causes that shake ,how can i prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most like the way you calculate the `y` position.  If you want it to be relative, you'd have to use just the delta value (and only use the stageY value to determine up or down)

```
var direction:int = eve.stageY > lastPosY ? 1 : -1; //if the latest mouse/touch position is greater than before (lower on the screen), use a value of 1 (down)
movieClipsArray[i].y -= delta_posY * direction; //multiply the delta by the direction
```

That said, you may find it much easier to use a container and scroll that container.  If you're using AnimateCC you could just select all your clips, hit F8 and make a new MovieClip that contains them all.  Or, do it through code:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(container);

container.addChild(mc1); //do this for all your clips instead of using an array
```

Then modify your code like so:

```
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, fl_TouchBeginHandler);
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, fl_TouchMoveHandler);

var offset: Number = 0;
function fl_TouchBeginHandler(eve: TouchEvent): void {
    offset = container.y - eve.stageY;
    //offset is the initial difference between the touch point and container's y. You use this to make sure it doesn't jump when you first touch it
}

function fl_TouchMoveHandler(eve: TouchEvent): void {
    container.y = eve.stageY + offset
}
```

Comment: Dear BadFeelingAboutThis thanks aloot , but about my case i think because of bad English i wasn't able to clarify it,i have an array of movie clips of   the players of my game which i get the data from php side but each of these player movie clips contains some other movie clips like the player pic ,button and .... and i added the drage event listener to the stage

Comment: but when i drage if  i do it on the players movie clips the child movie clips get recognized as target by the event and this is causing the problem,because of the eve.stageY,i try thing like  eve.stopPropagation(); which solved the problem but just the parts which no child exsits(the stage it self ) is possible to drage  and your help full post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328666/flash-as3-how-to-disable-child-swf-mouse-clicks-without-disabling-mouse-hove

Comment: the eve.stopPropagation() almost solved the problem but my issue is that the child which the stage event has bubbled to it recognised the stageY of it self not the stage which is the owner of the event listener

Comment: and about your answer on my question there is a problem ,as the player movieclips are childs of the stage and they have their own childs like player pic and so on ... theses nested child wich are possible to be targeted by draging isnt acually possible to calculate the offset to the stage which is the main container